# How to cast an exported function to a function type?

Tags: typescript, casting

I'm writing Express middleware and I'm finding it very hard to decide on how I'm supposed to typecast my functions. For example, I have an error handler:

```
export function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  ...
}
```

TypeScript rightfully complains that the arguments are any, so I cast it (`ErrorRequestHandler` comes from `@types/express`):

```
export function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  ...
} as ErrorRequestHandler;
```

But due to precedence, this is interpreted incorrectly, so I'm forced to wrap the cast in parentheses:

```
export (function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  ...
} as ErrorRequestHandler);
```

This gets rid of the type errors, but this makes the function declaration become a named function expression, something unexportable not to mention it looks ugly. So I'm stuck in a dilemma. How am I supposed to cast my error handler while exporting it also? Would I have to result to the old `<>` syntax?

Comment: I wish this were a [mcve] with no external types so I could play with it more easily.  Why don't you just give your function the right parameter and return types?  Assuming you can't, you might have to not export the function, and do `const eh = errorHandler as ErrorRequestHandler; export { eh as errorHandler }`.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I guess defining a const to cast is the only to go. As for explicitly typing arguments: I'm writing lots of middleware, so to repeat the arguments for each and every one seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
export const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: "prefix a type before a function"... [doesn't work for me](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/AQguE8AcFNgUQE4IPYIErQI4FdoGdQAJAQwDsATAG2gWAF5gAKAOleIQHMAuYM8AbQC6ASnoA+XqXABuAFCyQwaAA9IqUMAA8iFOiy4CJCtQRiAZtlIBjUAEtkpJUlRGqNRjQQAaYAiw+-PB9SFVBRAG8AX2AAehinXQBCWTjgAD8MzK0AWmzgUmQYIA)

Comment: @jcalz ah okay. I wasn't sure, but it does work if the function is a parameter. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/AQguE8AcFNgUQE4IPYIErQI4FdoGdQAJAQwDsATAG2gWAF5gAKAOleIQHMAuYM8AbQC6ASnoA+XqXABuAFCyQwAGbZSAY1ABLZKWXJkjBF0Qp0WXARIVqCUQG95igL6OQS-YwA8J1Bhz4iMioaMRV1LR1gGlMrYIRGaIAaYAQsZNS8ZNJoAA9QeydhOQB6YuAAP0qq4E8AWlrgUmQYIA

Comment: @jcalz Probably because then it becomes an expression once compiled. You can't export an expression (unless it's default). Same problem with `as`.

Answer (score -2):

```
export function errorHandler(err, req, res, next): ErrorRequestHandler {
  ...
}
```

Comment: no, that's the return value, not the function itself